# Powershell Script import csv on a SQL Server

Tags: powershell

I realize a script to import several excel file to update a table in a database SQL Server but when I run my script I have an error:

> invoke-sqlcmd : Syntaxe incorrecte vers '('.
>   Au caractère C:\Users\WEBadmin\Desktop\updateDb.ps1:38 : 15
>   + ...   $impcsv = invoke-sqlcmd -Database $db_name -Query $query  -serverin ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Here is my PS script:

```
$sql_instance_name = 'SERVER\SERV100'
$db_name = 'TOTO'
$table = 'dbo.F_ARTSTOCK'

$csv_folder = 'C:\IMPORTS'
$csv_completed_folder = 'C:\done'
$batchsize = 50000 

# assuming only csv-files you want to import are located in $csv_folder
$csv_files = Get-Childitem -Path $csv_folder -Filter '*.csv'

# Build the sqlbulkcopy connection, and set the timeout to infinite 
$connectionstring = "Data Source=$sql_instance_name;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=$db_name;" 
$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring, [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock) 
$bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = $table 
$bulkcopy.bulkcopyTimeout = 0 
$bulkcopy.batchsize = $batchsize 

foreach($file in $csv_files) {
    $impcsv = $file.FullName

    write-host "Processing file ..........$impcsv" -foregroundcolor green
    $data = import-csv $impcsv

    $count = 1

    foreach($i in $data) {

    Write-Host ($data | Format-Table | Out-String)

    $reference = $i.Reference
    $quantity = $i.Quantity

    $query = "UPDATE dbo.F_ARTSTOCK (AR_Ref,AS_QteSto)
              SET dbo.F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto = dbo.F_ARTSTOCK.AS_QteSto - '$quantity'
              WHERE dbo.F_ARTSTOCK.AR_Ref = '$reference'"

    $impcsv = invoke-sqlcmd -Database $db_name -Query $query  -serverinstance $sql_instance_name 

    write-host "Processing row ..........$count" -foregroundcolor green

    $count  = $count + 1

    }
}
```

Thank you for help guys.

Comment: I would suggest that you simply have the $query variable outputted to the console, for you to see what you are trying to execute. `Write-Host $query`

Comment: Apparently $i.Reference and $i.Quantity get NULL yet in my file these columns are filled.